# How to exclude referenced libraries from being exported when you export jar in VS Code for Java project (no build tool)

Tags: java, eclipse, visual-studio-code, jar, export

I have a Java Project for a JavaBean (multiple classes in a single project) with no build tools. In eclipse, I can export this project as JAR and I can select to export only the compiled classes without the referenced libraries.

In VS Code, when I select "Export JAR" from the JAVA Project tab, I am unable to remove the selection of the referenced libraries which is always copied to the output according to this config `{"java.project.outputPath":"bin"}`. Note that the referenced libraries are referenced using the `.classpath` file, not using the `.vscode` settings file with the section `"java.project.referencedLibraries"`.

Is it possible to export JAR in vscode the same way we export jar in eclipse?

What is the command line to export the needed jar?

I appreciate your help.

Tarek

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is an advanced way to export Jar in VS Code. See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-dependency/wiki/Export-Your-Project-to-a-Jar#advanced-custom-export-task

You can use the glob pattern here to customize the exclude list. e.g., a new rule like `!${compileOutput}/referenced.jar`.

Comment: I just had the time to check this out. I think I am making progress. I specified which subfolder to select from the `tasks.json` under the `elements` node, with the property `${compileOutput}/services`, I ended up having the `.class` files in the root folder of the JAR file. I cannot figure out how to export selected artifacts such as the `.class` files and keep them on the same relative path as they were in the original project, ie, under the `bin\services` folder. Can you help with this, please? If I don't maintain the same structure, it won't work!